# Javascript sort that ignores certain object values, leaving them exactly where they are

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a scenario where I'm sorting an array of objects, and need to maintain certain objects exactly where they are based on a value of a prop.

So currently I have, short:

```
const sorted = accounts.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.locked) return;
    if (b.locked) return;
    return b.price - a.price;
}
```

Obviously, this does not work as expected - while it ignores the specific `locked` case, it also ignores the sort comparison, and so if `a` was locked but `b` needs to move, `b` is also ignored instead of moving correctly.

The only other option I thought of is to mark which are `locked`, and then after the sort move them back in where they should be - don't think thats ideal, I'm looking for a more efficient way to leave the `locked` object in its exact place in the array while the other objects are moved around it, if possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd filter to gather all the non-locked items, then sort *that* array, then map the original array to replace the unlocked original items with the sorted unlocked ones:

```
const unlocked = accounts.filter(a => !a.locked);
unlocked.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
let i = 0;
const sorted = accounts.map(item => item.locked ? item : unlocked[i++]);
```